# Proof verification for Rudin PMA Exercise 6.7(a)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $(0,1]$ and $f$ is integrable on $[c,1]$ for every $c>0$. Define $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \lim_{c\to 0} \int_{c}^{1} f(x)dx$$
> if this limit exists (and is finite)
> . If $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, show that this definition of the integrals agrees with the old one.

My approach is as follows: Define
$$F(c) = \int_{c}^{1}f(x)dx$$
for $0\leq c\leq 1$.

Since $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, $|f(t)|\leq M$ for all $0\leq t\leq 1$. If $0\leq x<y\leq 1$, then
$$|F(x)-F(y)| = \left|\int_{y}^{1}f(t)dt - \int_{x}^{1}f(t)dt\right| = \left|\int_{x}^{y}f(t)dt\right|\leq M(y-x)$$
Therefore $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Thus $\lim_{c\to 0}\int_{c}^{1}f(x)dx = \lim_{c\to 0}F(c) = F(0) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$

---

Is my proof correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you assume $f$ to be bounded ?

Comment: @Falcon In Rudin, he only considers bounded functions for the Riemann integral, thus I assume it. If this is the case(f is bounded), is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof looks great. Note that you didn't really have to show that $F$ is continuous because it follows from part of the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus: $F(x) = -\int_1^x f(x)dx$ and since $f(x)$ is integrable then $F(x)$ is continuous. The FTC itself only says that $F$ is differentiable (and hence continuous) where $f$ is continuous, but part of the proof of the FTC is to show that $F$ is continuous everywhere (even where $f$ is not continuous, all that we need is that $f$ is integrable).